# Spring Boot не видит jsp

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Задался вопросом переноса проекта на Spring Boot. До этого все деплоилось на Томкат и криво-косо отрабатывало свое. Сейчас спринг не находит никаких jsp файлов и просто выкидывает ошибку "Whitelabel Error Page"
В application.properties пробовал прописать разные пути к jsp но ничего не помогало. Идеи кончились , идей больше нет.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>TestoWiki2.0</groupId>
<artifactId>Test</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Testowiki2.0.1</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <mysql.version>5.1.29</mysql.version>
</properties>



<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.ga</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Optional, test for static content, bootstrap CSS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Database -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

StartApplication

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
public class StartApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(StartApplication.class, args).registerShutdownHook();
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    return builder.sources(StartApplication.class);
}
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /webapp/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
security.basic.enabled=false
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/diplombd?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=admin12345
server.port=9999
```

П.с. Да я пробовал менять путь на "/WEB-INF/views/" , нет не помогло

Ну и ссылочку на гит всего прикладываю:

https://github.com/6ruceWayne/mark002.git

Comment: Скорее всего у вас packaging jar, а надо war. Еще можно попробовать изменить scope у dependecy tomcat-embed-jasper с provided на compiler(по умолчанию, просто удалить scope).

Comment: Если вы используете jsp, зачем подключили thymeleaf?

Answer (score 0):

В [Java™ Servlet Specification version 3.1](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html) написано:

> A special directory exists within the application hierarchy named
>   WEB-INF. This directory contains all things related to the application
>   that aren’t in the document root of the application. **The WEB-INF node
>   is not part of the public document tree of the application.** No file
>   contained in the WEB-INF directory may be served directly to a client
>   by the container. However, the contents of the WEB-INF directory are
>   visible to servlet code using the getResource and getResourceAsStream
>   method calls on the ServletContext, and may be exposed using the
>   RequestDispatcher calls.

Проще говоря, не надо складывать в WEB-INF jsp-файлы. Особенно, если они не обрабатываются каким-либо шаблонизатором.

Переместите jsp-файлы, доступ к которым требуется не через контроллер, в корень каталога webapp.

Comment: Перенес как сказали. Пересобрал проект , переписал строки в application.properties (сначала попробовал так же без них). Иииии...всеровно не работает =(

Comment: А почему, простите, "не надо складывать в WEB-INF jsp-файлы"?

Answer (score 0):

JSP вообще не рекомендуют использовать (знатоки), лучше Thymeleaf. Попробуйте сделать компайл pomx.xml заново...и очистить. И рекомендую в properties убрать WhiteLabel - server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false и вы скорей всего увидите ошибку 404